# every php file returns 500 internal server error on Apache server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have searched for the same error occurring elsewhere and the only set of answers that come close are at:

[Any .php file causing INTERNAL SERVER ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865117/any-php-file-causing-internal-server-error)

But they don't help with my current predicament.

I'm trying to fix my other half's dad's croquet website and I deleted the .htaccess file while I was updating the files.

This is a WordPress website.

All the new files are there barring the .htaccess file. Tried a few htaccess files recommended across the web, but still all I get when trying to kickstart any php files is the 500 Internal Server Error message.

The web host is Easily, which is in itself fun and games.

Anyone got any suggestions what I might try next?

Checked the logs, and nothing particularly helpful sticks out.

Thanks a million.

Dave

Comment: Are you sure that you have checked the correct error log? A 500 error means that it is a server error and could be _anything_ (misconfiguration, missing php libraries, file permission errors etc). It's virtually impossible for us to guess what the error is without a proper error message.

Comment: 500 usually occurred due to misconfig in .htaccess file, paste code of .htaccess file.

Comment: @Nilay - Any fatal PHP error also returns 500 so it could be a lot of things.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah, i know it but in most of case it occurred due to .htaccess, so i think first of all check .htaccess file

Comment: @Nilay - I agree that it's a good place to start.

Comment: Use Winscp or putty to access your server and rename all .htaccess files in your website path. Let me give you an example to understand, if your website path is /var/www/vhosts/directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4 . you need to check all directories from 1 to 4 or whatever directories you got and for the htaccess files and rename .htaccess to htaccess-bak.txt. Also using Winscp right click your root website folder where wordpress is installed then set the folder 755 chmod recursively.

Comment: if the .htaccess fixing doesn't work, then check the permission of files. If it is 777, then change the permissions of all the files to 775 or 755.